# Is there any difference between hololens' viewport and UE4's viewport?

Tags: viewport, unreal-engine4, hololens

Our main idea is that we take a picture by hololens then we get the 2D coordinates of something(the thermos and the printer) in this picture. Then we deproject these two things' 2D coordinates of their screenshot back to 3D coordinates in the unreal world, then we draw a box at coordinates' position.

However, as you can see, we marked the thermos(the first picture) and the printer(the second picture) with the 3D coordinates we calculated from their coordinates in their 2D screenshot with a static mesh. But, they have an obvious offset to left down. We speculate that maybe such kind of problem comes from the reason that our camera center is wrong.

Did you meet or solve such kind of problem? Can you give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

[image: first]

[image: second]

Answer (score 0):

We noticed that you already have a new one with more information in Microsoft Q&A community platform. It seems like where exactly is returned from `GetActorLocation` is **headset position** and there is an offset from **location of PV camera**. So that, it is recommended you using the [GetPVCameraToWorldTransform](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Plugins/HoloLensAR/UHoloLensARFunctionLibrary/GetPVCameraToWorldTransform/index.html) API which in HoloLensARFunctionLibrary.h header file to find the camera position in World Space. And then [GetWorldSpaceRayFromCameraPoint](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Plugins/HoloLensAR/UHoloLensARFunctionLibrary/GetWorldSpaceRayFromCameraPoint/index.html) can help to find what exists in world space at a particular pixel coordinate. For more detail about how to implement this solution, please go through this section: [Find Camera Positions in World Space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/unreal-hololens-camera?tabs=426#find-camera-positions-in-world-space)